# JMH - Diff between getPrimaryResults and getSecondaryResults

Tags: microbenchmark, jmh

What is the difference between the `getPrimaryResults` and `getSecondaryResults` methods of the `RunResults` class in JMH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't verified it on code basis but as I understand it primary results are figures that are produced solely by JMH (the time measurements) whereas secondary results are obtained by means of additional tools like profilers.

UPDATE: I just have seen that the StackProfiler is part of JMH meaning my definition is not completely valid.

UPDATE 2: Meanwhile, Aleksey Shipilev provided a much clearer definition in his comment.

Below you find some lines extracted from a benchmark result. I started the benchmark with '-prof stack'

```
[java] Iteration  10: 104439194.250 ±(99.9%) 7883662.439 ns/op
[java]                  ·stack: <delayed till summary>
...
[java]   118162555.108 ±(99.9%) 8317229.030 ns/op [Average]
[java]   (min, avg, max) = (102325413.750, 118162555.108, 149303159.000), stdev = 12448837.807
[java]   CI (99.9%): [109845326.078, 126479784.138] (assumes normal distribution)
...
[java] Secondary result "·stack":
[java] Stack profiler:
[java] ....[Thread state distributions]....................................................................
[java]  87.3%         RUNNABLE
[java]  12.7%         WAITING
[java] ....[Thread state: RUNNABLE]....................................................................    ....
[java]  82.3%  94.3% sun.management.ThreadImpl.getThreadTotalCpuTime0
```

As you can see, the results from the stack profiler are marked as Secondary results. Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks +1, I will research this a little and go back to accept the answer!

Comment: In other words, the "primary" result is the *actual* *major* performance result for the test. "Secondary" results are the auxiliary data: profiler results, asymmetric subtests results, etc. There is only one primary result per test, and may be many secondary.